# Web based .pdf data interpreter?

Tags: pdf, language-agnostic

Is there an web based API or software that can be used to interpret numerical data from a .pdf document and display the results on a web page? Is it even possible to do this?

Thx.

Comment: Sure its POSSIBLE. For example http://webification.com/tag/parse-pdf-javascript-hmtl5 wouldn't work it was not.

Comment: I don't want to simply parse .pdf documents - I want to read and interpret them.

Answer (score 0):

Not that I know of.

But since you seem to be an adapt of Rails and Heroku, I am referring to this [SO thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/773193/ruby-reading-pdf-files) so you could write a Service that can read PDF files, and send the data back to the client. This could very well be on Heroku.

Contact me if you need help ;)