# Can I get Co-ordinates of a specific word from a pdf using Ruby?

Tags: python, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3

I need to hide text from a pdf. Is there any Ruby or python Library for parsing pdf and getting the co-ordinates of a specific word or word.

```
        Please help me out to solve the problem.
```

Thank you and regards.

Comment: Not really a programming question?  Or perhaps insufficiently specified.  Why Python or Ruby in particular?  What does "hide" mean?  Why aren't you simply using PDF generating tools to re-distill the document with the specific "word or word[sic]" removed?

Comment: I am working with ruby on rails. Thats why I specified ruby. Hide in the sense I want to parse the pdf and after parsing need to hide some information in that pdf for example parse a pdf resume and hide contact details like email or address.

Answer (score 0):

I wonder if this might solve part of your problem: [PDF::Writer](http://ruby-pdf.rubyforge.org/pdf-writer/manual/index.html) ... and perhaps this [Stack Overflow: Ruby: Reading PDF files](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/773193/ruby-reading-pdf-files) might help you extract the text from your inputs.  You might be able to stitch together some sort of extract-filter-encode function by carefully reading these and any code examples to which they refer.